# Minimum length subarray such that it has a subsequence with an xor sum of 0

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, xor

I'm stuck on this one problem from a competitive programming archive which says:

```
Given an array of integers A of length n, we need to find the minimum length
subarray such that it has a subsequence with an xor sum of 0. (Subarray is a
contiguous segment of an array and subsequence is a sequence that can be
derived from a subarray by deleting zero or more elements.) The resulting
subarray must have a length of at least 1. (Empty subarray cannot be an answer.)

1 <= n <= 10^5
1 <= A[i] <= 10^9
```

Since the constraints are huge, the typical Dynamic Programming approach doesn't seem to work. I've read about doing Gaussian Elimination mod 2, but I don't see how it is applicable to this question. Since there can be exponential number of solutions to that System of Equations, picking the minimum length subarray shouldn't be so easy to do. I've also considered doing a Sliding Window approach but I don't know how adding the next number to our data structure and removing the first numbers can be supported. A bitset approach similar to subset sum problem wouldn't work either as well because numbers are up to 10^9 and we can't use up that much memory.

These are all the things that I tried to solve this problem. Any ideas and resources are welcome. If there is an efficient algorithm for this task, please let me know.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask]. Lastly please read [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What do you mean? I don't seem be to violating anything in the any of the links that you provided. I shared my "specific programming problem" that I have been trying to solve for days and I provided "what I tried to solve the problem". I'm just asking for any ideas or tips about this question.

Comment: @astro just read the links. IMO your question doesn't violate anything, but can be improved, e.g. by adding (perhaps, partial) code from your attempts, and an input example(s) that an approach can be tested against

Comment: as for the question, adding and removing numbers from a data structure - use an int. Xor with a number to add, xor with the same number again to remove

Comment: Another idea: if there is an efficient sliding window algorithm (amortized less than linear time compute for each window) for a fixed subarray size, you could binary search on each subarray size; the transition from each subarray to another involves replacing one element in the window at a time. However, I'm not aware of any such algorithm; maybe the Gaussian Elimination mod 2 can be tweaked so that this would work, but my understanding is that it's exponential in the worst case so I'm not sure of this.

Comment: How much time and space do you have to your disposal?

Comment: The solution should be able to run under 1 second and use less than 256mb. Online judges typically can do 10^8 operations in a second so the algorithm should be faster than O(n^2) as n can be up to 10^5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take any length-30 subarray.  Every A[i] < 2<sup>30</sup>, so there are two possibilities:

1. The 30 integers are linearly (with xor) independent, in which case you can make *any* 30-bit integer, including whichever one is next in the array, by xoring together the appropriate subsequence; or
2. The 30 integers are *not* linearly independent, in which case you can make 0 by xoring together the appropriate non-empty subsequence.

In either case, the subarray plus the next element has a subsequence that xors to 0.  The length of the smallest subarray with such a subsequence is therefore always <= 31, unless the array is short and has no such subsequence at all.

With the constraint that N < 10<sup>5</sup>, you've got plenty of time to try Gaussian elimination on every subarray with length < 31.

Remember: you don't actually have to find a subsequence that xors to zero.  You just need to use Gaussian elimination to see if the integers in the subarray are linearly independent.

Here's an example implementation in python (for clarity, even though python is slow):

```python
def smallestSubarrayLength(A):
    rows = [0]*32
    bestLength = None

    # add rows starting at start to a Gaussian elimination
    for start in range(len(A)):
        n=1
        rows[0] = A[start]
        for i in range(1,min(32,len(A)-start)):
            newrow = A[start+i]
            for j in range(n):
                # rows will be in descending order,
                # and each entry will have a different high bit
                oldrow = rows[j]
                if (newrow > oldrow):
                    rows[j] = newrow
                    newrow = min(oldrow, newrow ^ oldrow)
                else:
                    newrow = min(newrow, newrow ^ oldrow)
            rows[n] = newrow
            n += 1
            if newrow == 0:
                # The rows are not linearly independent
                if bestLength == None or n < bestLength:
                    bestLength = n
                break
    return bestLength
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on this approach a little bit? The answer can definitely be less than 30, how do we account for such cases? Doing gaussian elimination on every subarray doesn't seem feasible because there are O(n^2) subarrays, multiplied with the time complexity of gaussian elimination, it will definitely exceed the time limit.

Comment: @astro There will be only 30n subarrays with length < 31.  (Also you could grow the subarray length gradually and perform reduction operations on the new element to further improve the speed)

Comment: +1. Alt explanation of short lengths: For any two sets of ints S & T, if xor(S) = xor(T) then xor(S U T) = 0. To have a subarray of length k with no subsequence that xor's to 0, we'd need each of the 2^k subsequences to xor to different values. Since 10^9 has 30 bits, we can make at most 2^30 different ints so the max possible bad subarray has 30 elts; at 31+ there must be a solution.

Comment: @astro I think you misread it.  The answer is *always* 31 or less.

Comment: I got it. Here is my approach: I keep a sliding window like structure and while the determinant of the matrix is 1, I shrink the window from the left and keep expanding it from the right. Now, the question is how do I efficiently calculate determinants as I keep adding and removing elements? Since, before adding the next element we have applied some operations to the rest of the elements and we would need to apply the same operations to this new element as well. Currently I'm calculating determinants from scratch each time, which does 30^3*10^5 operations at most, which is very slow.

Comment: Yeah, determinants are slow and that sounds a little too complicated.  I added an example implementation along the lines of what @PeterdeRivaz suggested.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. How did you even come up with such a solution, I'm literally in awe :D Do you have any further readings to recommend about these type of questions? Thank you so much by the way, I've been thinking about this question for so long and you just made my day :)

Comment: Thanks.  It's just experience, and they don't all turn out this well.